# Pegar registros no DataGridView e jogar em um label

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms

Gente, minha ideia é a seguinte, quero pegar registros em uma DataGridView e jogar em cinco labels. Cada um corresponde a um comando, e esses labels irão mudar para outro registro assim que clicados.

Exemplo:

1. `Label1.Text = "Você gosta de programar?";` (O label de pergunta não terá nenhuma ação, apenas será alterado com o clique em algum dos outros)
2. `Label2.Text = "Gosto";` (Esse label receberá ações de adicionar cinco pontos aos usuários, ele mudará o texto de todos os labels.)
3. `Label3.Text = "Mais ou menos";` (Este label fará o mesmo que o `label2`.)

Com o clique do usuário, os labels pegariam o próximo registro do usuário até que todos os registros acabassem.

Tentei colocar um while com uma variável fazendo a contagem de linhas, mas o label não muda seu texto.

Esse é o meu código atual:

```
label1.Text = questoesTableAdapter.ConsultaPergunta(1);

int numero_Linhas = dataGridView1.RowCount;
int i =1;
while (i < numero_Linhas)
{
    label1.Text = questoesTableAdapter.ConsultaPergunta(i);
    label2.Text = i.ToString();

    ++i;
}
```

Estou usando apenas dois label's para teste, um recebe o contador, e o outro o texto da pergunta.

Minha tabela é a seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O problema é que o `label1` não mostra os dados que você precisa? Se sim, isso deve ser um problema dentro do método `questoesTableAdapter.ConsultaPergunta(i);`, você se certificou de que ele retorna os dados corretamente? Eu ainda não consigo entender o intuito do `while` - ele vai mudar o texto do `label` a cada execução, isso parece errado. Você tem como [edit] sua pergunta e adicionar mais detalhes? Tanto o código dos métodos que usa como informações sobre como o app deve funcionar.

Comment: o seu titulo esta ... Pegar registros no SQL Server 2014 e jogar em um label ...e na descrição ...quero pegar registros em uma DataGridView e jogar em cinco labels ... um pouco confuso ..

Comment: Primeiramente peço desculpas a vocês pela falta de informação na minha pergunta. Ainda tô pegando o jeito com essa coisa de pedir ajuda em fóruns...

Bom, a ideia é contar o total de colunas na DataGridView, assim que contar, fazer um while com esse total.

Dentro do "while", quero ter cinco labels tendo mudanças de textos (textos saem da tabela no DataGridView) assim que qualquer um deles for clicado. Por exemplo:

label_pergunta.Text = "Qual seu nome?";

label_resposta1.Text = "Gian";
label_resposta2.Text = "Bueno";
label_resposta3.Text = "Marconcilio";
label_resposta4.Text = "Lucas";

Comment: Gian, dá uma conferida no seu comentário aqui encima. Dá pra entender o código direito? Não, né? Pois então, dica pro: quando rolarem dúvidas edite sua pergunta e dê um toque através dum comentário `@fulano, editei a pergunta e tal e tal`.